# Android WiFiDirect service discovery confusion

Tags: android, wifi-direct, service-discovery

I'm trying to use WiFi Direct service discovery to connect two android phones. I'm only interested in one phone being able to send a connection request. I thought what I needed to do was register a local service on one phone, and discover the service on the other phone, and after discovering it I can connect to it. But it seems like I have to do the discovery stuff on both phones in order for it to work...so I'm just confused on what's happening. I'm using [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd-wifi-direct.html). Can anyone help me understand what's necessary to have the two phones connect? I can't have one phone only registering and the other phone only discovering?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you are trying to do. You can actually discover other devices and perform a connection without having a Service Discovery layer on top. Peer Discovery and Service discovery are not the same thing. Peer discovery involves detecting all of the nearby devices that use Wifi Direct while Service Discovery involves only discovering devices that advertise a specific kind of service.

You should start with this other [Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html) before moving on to Service Discovery which is a more advanced topic.

Comment: you make mention of Service Discovery as a "layer on top", does Service Discovery have a dependency on Peer Discovery? Will the basic service registration and service discovery code described here: https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd-wifi-direct work on its own, or does it require the Peer Discovery code to also be running in the app in order to discover services on another device?

Comment: @HoloSheep there's not a direct dependency between the two. With that being said, if you are interested in doing this for WiFi p2p, you do need to be able to first find a peer, connect to it and then you would be able to find services for that peer.

Comment: are you saying that with WiFI Direct P2P if you want to discover a service, that a peer needs to first connect to the device that is advertising that service before the peer will know that the service is available? Isn't the idea of Service Discovery that nearby devices can first discover an advertised service and then connect to the device that is advertising it? It sounds like you are saying that it works the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect other devices using peer discovery but there is no need for service discovery to exchange data or service. You can use socket connection also after connecting the devices ex - for exchanging of files .

Answer (score 0):

It's worth to mention that using ServiceDiscovery you can sent some additional data, like running port or something else in `record` map (in DNS-SD at least).